# Pass value from controller to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating project using angularjs.I have problem while creating custom directive.Actually I want to send the value from controller to directive but I got undefined. Here is my code:

Here is Directive

```
.directive('angularData', function ($parse) {
    return {
      template: false,
      scope: {
        chart: '=lineChartData'
      },
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace: true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element,attrs) {
        var canvas, context, chart, options;
        console.log(attrs)
        console.log(scope.chart) //undefiend
        console.log(chart) //undefiend
      }
    };
});
```

Here is Html where I call the Directive

```
<canvas id="test" angular-data ="lineChartData" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
```

Here is controller Code

```
$scope.lineChartData = {
    labels :[1,4,8,6,8],
    datasets : [
      {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data : [1,4,8,6,8]
      }  
    ]
}
```

Comment: this is also not works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the `link` function in your directive, put a watcher:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module('myApp').directive('angularData', function ($q, $parse) {
    return {
      //template: false,
      restrict: 'A',
      //replace: true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element,attrs) {
       scope.$watch(attrs.angularData, function(value) {
         console.log(value);
        });
      }
    };
  });
angular.module('myApp').controller("myCtl", function($scope) {
 $scope.lineChartData={a:2, b:"test"};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtl"> 
    <canvas id="test" angular-data ="lineChartData" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ AlexanderMP: I want to use this directive multiple times on one page

Comment: Yes, and you can do that. This `link` function will be individual for every element.
This is the *proper* way read a directive. I used similar code with custom validation scenarios. You can access `element` to get the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you declaring the controller inside the directive? That way it will have access to the data from the controller ... I.e.,

```
return {
  template: false,
  scope: {
    chart: '=lineChartData'
  },
  controller: SomeController,
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  ...
```

Then you have access to the controller's data via the scope on the directive's link.

Answer (score 0):

In you html try this,

```
<canvas id="test" angular-data line-chart-data="lineChartData" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

inside you DOM element  pass your $scope variable like this: chart = lineChartData

hope this helps,gokd luck.